# if statement not executing in while(true) loop

Tags: java, swing, loops

I am trying to have my program break out of a while loop when a button on the gui is pressed.

I have a thread which launches the GUI thread and the waits until an apply button is pressed.
Here is the code:

```
public void run() {     

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }           
        });

        // Wait until apply button clicked and set team
        while(true) {

            applyClicked = gui.getApplyClicked();
            if (applyClicked == true) {
                teamYellow = gui.getTeam();
                break;
            }   
        }
```

However even when I click apply and the applyClicked becomes true within the GUI it does not execute that if statement.

However if I add a print line underneath the while true it works ok.

I also debugged it running line by line and the variables set correctly and it works.

Why doesn't this work when I don't have a println? Is it something to do with threads?

Thanks

Comment: `volatile`? (also, busy wait loops, bad!)

Comment: volatile worked. How else would I get the boolean from the gui to the class which contains that loop without a busy wait loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're executing a busy-wait loop, which will I guess take all of your cpu power.
You should instead add an actionListener on your apply-button and do your stuff in the actionPerformed method.

Comment: Hi thats what I am currently doing in the gui class. The actionPerformed method changes the boolean which says whether the button has been clicked or not. I then use a getter in the same class to get this boolean in my class which contains the loop above.

Comment: Couldn't you add this class as a listener on the buttons event? Then you could remove the busy-wait loop which you sure don't want to have.

Comment: Sorry not too sure how to do that. So the class that currently has the busy-wait loop is called Runner, and the gui class is called MainGui with its instance called gui in the Runner class. Currently I call `log.apply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {...`

in the MainGui class where log is a panel containing the button. How would I add the Runner class as a listener

Comment: `public class Runner implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { do stuff in here
    }` and then you could for instance add the `Runner` as an argument to the MainGui constructor and in the constructor do `public MainGui(Runner runner) {
log.apply.addActionListener(runner);
        }`

Comment: Ok, so the code that I had in the action listener for the apply button in MainGui now goes in the action listener within Runner?

I have added the code you suggested to MainGui and then moved the action code to Runner however it does nothing when the button is clicked.

Comment: Could you update your code example in the question? Then I might see what's wrong.

Comment: Never mind I got it too work. I was instantiating the Gui before I called the invokeLater method. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if you mark the question as answered:-).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for exactly, but just in case, define `applyClicked` outside the loop and declare the loop as `while(!applyClicked)` so that the break is not needed, because if `applyClicked` is true, the loop will exit on its own. If that still doesn't work, run the new code with the debugger. This may or may not work, it's just a suggestion.